# Creating Tiles with Divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show two coloured tiles, one to the left, one to the right.  They each have a number in a larger font and a title in a smaller font. They should have some padding around the edge so that the text doesn't bump against the edge of the tile.

They should fill the container they the sit in horizontally.  I have set each of the two tiles to 45% width with an element in the middle of 10%, totalling 100%.

I have achieved this with a Table and it all works fine.  But I would rather use Divs that can be re-used more easily.

However, when I try to build it with Divs, the border seems to make the whole thing too wide so that it doesn't fit.  I can't see why. I've tried combinations of Border, Margin and Padding.

```css
.info-tile {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
.info-tile-large-text {
  font-size: 400%
}
.info-tile-small-text,
.info-tile-large-text {}
```

```html
<div>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="info-tile pending-enquiry-colours" style="width:45%;"><span class="info-tile-large-text">86</span>
        <br/><span>Pending Enquiries</span>
      </td>
      <td class="" style="width:10%"></td>
      <td class="info-tile active-enquiry-colours" style="width:45%;"><span class="info-tile-large-text">15</span>
        <br /><span>Active Enquiries</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div>
    <div class="info-tile pending-enquiry-colours" style="width:45%; float: left;"><span class="info-tile-large-text">86</span>
      <br/><span class="info-tile-small-text">Pending Enquiries</span>
    </div>
    <div style="width:10%; float: left" ;></div>
    <div class="info-tile active-enquiry-colours" style="width:45%; float: right;"><span class="info-tile-large-text">15</span>
      <br /><span class="info-tile-small-text">Active Enquiries</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I think the padding is adding onto the sizes of your div's.  Have you tried adding box-sizing: border-box; to your info-tile class?

Comment: To include the border/padding in your width/height calculations add `* {box-sizing:border-box;}`

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/103/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` on any element that you are having that problem with (aka all of your tiles).

By default, most browsers set `box-sizing` to `content`, meaning that if you set the width of an element to `400px`, and add `padding: 30px`, it computes the total size of the element to be `460px`.

`box-sizing: border-box` does the opposite, where a set width will never be exceeded by padding.

Comment: Thanks very much @Aeolingamenfel

Comment: No problem. I can't tell you the amount of times I've run into this issue.

Comment: @Chris All that's happened is changing the definition of "width" by using box-sizing. If you had understood how width works in CSS, this would not be an issue at all. box-sizing doesn't "fix" anything. Only the values you originally used were a problem.